# Data not getting in action form

Tags: java, struts

Hi all I am beginner in java struts i am creating simple registration form but after submitting form null is inserting in database table.I have created form class name as RegistrationForm.java Program is running but null is inserting  my action code is ---

```
public class RegistrationAction extends Action {    
     private Connection con = null;    
     public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,  
                HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
                throws Exception {  

            ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();  

            RegistrationForm objReg = new RegistrationForm();
            String userName = (String) objReg.getTxtusername();
            String userPass = (String) objReg.getTxtpassword();  

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();    
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///test", "root", "");    
            if (!con.isClosed()) {   
                PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement)             con.prepareStatement("INSERT   >INTO tblUserdetails(fldUsername,fldPassword) VALUES (?,?) ");  

                ps.setString(1, userName);  
                ps.setString(2, userPass);  

                ps.execute();  
            } else {  
                errors.add("SQL", new ActionMessage("error.SQLConnectivity"));  
            }  
            return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);  
       }  
}
```

---

```
package com.vaannila.form;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;

public class RegistrationForm extends ActionForm {
    private String txtusername;
    private String txtpassword;
    private String txtrepassword;
    private String txtemail;

    public String getTxtusername() {
        return txtusername;
    }

    public void setTxtusername(String txtusername) {
        this.txtusername = txtusername;
    }

    public String getTxtpassword() {
        return txtpassword;
    }

    public void setTxtpassword(String txtpassword) {
        this.txtpassword = txtpassword;
    }
}
```

Comment: please update your question with the detail

Comment: just forget the part of inserting into the database (delete it). Can you print out the value of the username on the console by using System.out.println. Since your struts code seems to be correct

Answer (score 0):

You created a brand new object RegistrationForm, therefore there is no value in it. It should be

```
RegistrationForm objReg = (RegistrationForm) form;
```

Comment: after changing still null is inserting in database table userName,userPass is null

Comment: Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:

    Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).

Comment: @user1905837: Try adding some context to explain the code sections. I.e., don't just paste the code in - also explain what all the pieces of code are.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `RegistrationForm`:

```
RegistrationForm objReg = new RegistrationForm();
```

You want to use the *existing* form, provided by the framework:

```
RegistrationForm objReg = (RegistrationForm) form;
```

`objReg` is a yucky name.

Comment: after changing still null is inserting in database table userName,userPass is null

Comment: @user1905837 Are they null from the form? Show your form class. Show your HTML.

Comment: @user1905837 and your struts-config as well

Answer (score 0):

Your form field name and the name what you are providing in ActionForm should be same.
For example:

helloWorld.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="login.do">
<pre>
User Name : <input type="text" name="uname"/>
Password : <input type="password" name="pass"/>
<input type="submit" value="LogIN">
</pre>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

helloWorldForm.java

```
private String uname,pass;

and in struts ur entry should like

    <action path="/login" type="com.app.core.biswa.AppLoginAction" name="helloWorldForm" scope="session" validate="true" input="/helloWorld.jsp">
```

It will definitely work.